# Asynchronous operation in ASP.Net custom handler

Tags: asp.net, multithreading

I use a 1x1 image tag to implement tracking on my website. The src attribute of the image tag is a call to a custom asp.net handler that I've written.

This handler inserts some data to the database. It gets millions of hits a day so I need the database insert to be async.

I've never done multithreaded programming so am seeking some assistance on how to go about this.

My handler should invoke a new thread which inserts data to the database and immediately return the 1x1 image to the client.

If the database insert is slow, the handler should not wait till it is finished but immediately return the image to the client.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at following links for good understanding of various ways to implement async processing and related code examples:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227433.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164128.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163463.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/AsyncBLOB.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2010/04/14/performing-asynchronous-work-or-tasks-in-asp-net-applications.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot. If the handler immediatedly returns the image while the thread it invoked is still doing the insert, does the thread remain alive until it finishes or is the thread killed as soon as the handler returns?